# Declare properties for subview controller in header

Tags: objective-c, xcode

`NameSubViewController` and `NameSubView` are added in `ViewController.m`:

```
#import "NameSubViewController.h"
#import "NameSubView.h"

...

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NameSubViewController *nameController = [[NameSubViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NameSubViewController" bundle:nil];
NameSubView *nameSubView = (NameSubView *)[nameController view];
}
```

But I want to make properties for them so I can access them from every part of the view. What to write in `ViewController.h` to declare the properties there instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NameSubView *nameSubView;
```

.m
under line `@implementation`

```
@synthesize nameSubView;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to declare it like UIViewController that's why it didn't work.